# how to add bar graphs and pie charts using project clarity

Tags: vmware-clarity, clarity

i need add some bar graphs and pie charts based on my data available , but unfortunately i couldn't  find those templates in project clarity website. kindly help me in this

NA

NA

Answer (score 0):

Clarity does not have any charts, which is why you don't see any in the documentation. I suggest looking at some of the other useful Angular charting libraries to handle this.

https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+charts